# ¿Cómo convertir de Katakana a Hiragana?

Tags: java, localización

Quiero convertir una cadena de caracteres japoneses de katakana a hiragana. Dejando todos los caracteres que no sean katakana tal cual.
He probado con toUpperCase y toLowerCase con el Locale JAPANESE, pero ambos dejan la cadena sin modificar.

```
public class KataKanaAHiragana {

    static String entrada = "スタックオベルフロウ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( entrada.toUpperCase(Locale.JAPANESE) );
        System.out.println( entrada.toLowerCase(Locale.JAPANESE) );
    }
}
```

El resultado que obtengo en ambos casos es :

> スタックオベルフロウ

Y lo que quiero obtener es :

> すたっくおべるふろう

Comment: No tengo ni idea de cómo se hace, pero encontré algunas referencias en Internet que simplemente desplazan el caracter algunas posiciones, como ésta: https://code.google.com/p/kurikosu/source/browse/trunk/kurikosu/src/main/java/org/kurikosu/transcription/Hiragana2Katakana.java?r=13

Comment: En japonés katakana, hiragana y kanjies son caracteres que se escriben igual en mayúsculas y minúsculas, de allí el problema. La forma tradicional de convertir caracteres mayúsculas y minúsculas es con una suma o resta, necesitas saber en que posiciones se encuentran los subconjuntos de caracteres entre los que quieres convertir y si están ordenados progresivamente saber que distancia hay entre ellos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Importante

### Hay dos versiones de Katakana, medio-ancho y ancho-completo.

tenemos que determinar la versión!

```
public static String AHiragana(String KatakanaString)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Character c : KatakanaString.toCharArray())
    {
        // Es un character medio-ancho?
        if(('\uff66' <= c) && (c <= '\uff9d'))
        {
            sb.append((char)(c-0xcf25));
        }
        else if(('\u30a1' <= c) && (c <= '\u30fe')) // ancho-completo
        {
            sb.append((char)(c-0x60));
        }
        else
        {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: No tenía ni idea. Muchas gracias. Voy a tener que incorporarlo.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos De nada! :-)

Answer (score 1):

He podido resolverlo basándome en el [código](https://code.google.com/p/kurikosu/source/browse/trunk/kurikosu/src/main/java/org/kurikosu/transcription/Hiragana2Katakana.java?r=13) que menciona Arturo Tena.

```
private static final int KATAKANA_A_HIRAGANA = - 6 * 16;

public static String katakanaAHiragana(String cadena) {

    StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder( cadena.length() );

    for (int indice = 0; indice < cadena.length(); indice++) {

        final char caracter = cadena.charAt(indice);
        final char carConvertido;
        if ( caracter == 'ー') {
            //  'ー' es un carácter que también puede ser usado 
            // en katakana y que se deja igual en hiragana.
            carConvertido = caracter;
        } else if ( caracter>='ァ' && caracter<='ヴ' ) {
             carConvertido = (char) (((int) caracter) + KATAKANA_A_HIRAGANA );
        }
        else
        {
            // No tocar los caracteres que no son katakana
            carConvertido = caracter;
        }
        resultado.append(carConvertido);
    }

    return resultado.toString();
}
```